# Method resolution in extension methods with optional parameters

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, resolution, optional-parameters

I have the following couple of extension methods, which are in the same namespace and assembly:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string NullSafeToString(this DateTime? possiblyNullDateTime, string format, string nullString = "")
}

public static class NullableExtensions
{
    public static string NullSafeToString<T>(this Nullable<T> nullable, string nullString = "") where T : struct
}
```

My question is about method resolution. The following call (from another namespace) resolves to `ObjectExtensions.NullSafeToString` when I expected `DateTimeExtensions.NullSafeToString`:

```
DateTime? dateTime;
// ...
dateTime.NullSafeToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Removing the optional parameter from `DateTimeExtensions.NullSafeToString` causes it to resolve as expected.

Section 7.6.5.2 of the C# spec outlines the order of the namespaces searched, but because the above are in the same namespace, I'd expect it to use the rules in section 7.6.5.1.

I thought it'd match `DateTimeExtensions.NullSafeToString` because:

- Although they'll both have a first parameter type of `Nullable<DateTime>`, I thought a non-generic method (i.e. without the type parameter) would be considered first.
- I though the parameter lists would be considered without their optional parameters first

Can anyone clarify why it's picking `ObjectExtensions.NullSafeToString` over `DateTimeExtensions.NullSafeToString`?

(Aside: From other discussions on here, I suspect some people may disapprove of using extension method semantics to make dereferencing null-safe, but I find that used for limited scenarios like this, they make for more readable code. Also I know `Nullable.ToString` is already null-safe because the `Nullable` object itself isn't null, but that doesn't cater for parameters to the contained `ToString`, and I find that the explicitly named method indicates the null-safe intent.)

Comment: Overload resolution applies "less arguments == better".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem have nothing to do with extension method. It's about overload resolution and optional parameters.(7.5.3 Overload resolution of c# spec)
You can try this code

```
public static string NullSafeToString(DateTime? possiblyNullDateTime, string format, string nullString = "")
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    public static string NullSafeToString<T>(Nullable<T> nullable, string nullString = "") where T : struct
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    static void Test()
    {
        DateTime? datetime = DateTime.Now;
        NullSafeToString(datetime, "yyyyMMdd");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still not clear on is why it's picking ObjectExtensions.NullSafeToString over DateTimeExtensions.NullSafeToString. From 7.5.3.1:

"If MP is a non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is better than MQ".

I presume some other rule is coming into play first, but I'm not sure which.

Comment: Sorry - that should be 7.5.3.2 "Better function member".